# Is it $a^{48m+1}+b^{48n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{39} \Leftrightarrow a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{39}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \left\lbrace0\right\rbrace$,

is $a^{48m+1}+b^{48n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{39} \iff a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{39}$?

I think the answer is yes, but I can't prove it. Is there somebody who can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Show that $a^{12m+1}\equiv a\pmod{39}$ for all $a,m$. **Irrespective of whether $a$ and $39$ are coprime or not.** Little Fermat and Chinese remainder theorem are all you need.

Comment: I still don't know how to prove that ? Can you help me ?

Comment: What problems are you facing ? The answer provided by @Aqua is excellent .

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit but the Euler say if (a,m)=1. In this exercise a and b $\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think it works even if $m$ or $n$ is $0$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Euler theorem $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$$
if $\gcd(a,n )= 1$. Notice that $$\varphi (39) = 2\cdot 12 =24$$

---

**Edit: 12. 29. 2019**

- a) If $(a,39) =1$ then clearly also $(b,39)=1$ so we have $a^{24} \equiv 1$ and $b^{24} \equiv 1$ so  $a^{48m}a \equiv a$ and $b^{48n}b \equiv b$ and thus: $$a^{48m+1}+b^{48n+1} \equiv a+b$$ and the equivalence follows.
- b) If $(a,39) \ne 1$ then $3\mid a$ or $13 \mid a$ or $39\mid a$.

  - If $39\mid a$ then also $39\mid b$ and claim follows
  - If $3\mid a$ and $13\nmid a$ then if $3\mid a^{48m+1}+b^{48n+1} $ we have also $3\mid b$ so $3\mid a+b$ and vice versa. And for $13$ you can repeat a process in case a).
  - If $13\mid a$ and $3\nmid a$ then repeat a process from previous case

Comment: we can use euler theorem when a and n is coprime, but in this exercercise a and m is abitrary number in Z

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html

For $3\mid x(x^2-1),$

and $13|x(x^{12}-1)$

$[3,13]$ will divide $x(x^{[2,12]}-1)$ and hence $x(x^{12m}-1)$ for any integer $m$

Comment: @Downvoter, please find the updated answer

Comment: I didn't down voted but the hint can be elaborated a little more so that the O.P can understand.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly why $13|x(x^{12}-1)$?

Comment: @Nguyen, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html and the updated post

Comment: Either $\gcd(x, 13) = 1$ and so $x^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ and $13|x^{12} -1$.  or $\gcd(x,13) = 13$ and so $13|x$.  Either way, $13|x\cdot (x^{12}-1)$.... Another way of saying this is if $p$ is prime then $a^p \equiv a$ (whether $a$ is or is not a multiple of $p$.  [If $a$ isn't a multiple of $p$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ so $a^{p-1}a\equiv a$.  And if $a$ *is* a multiple of $p$ then $a \equiv 0$ and $a^p \equiv 0$.])

Answer (score 1):

Note that $39=3\times13$, and $3$ and $13 $ are prime.

Using Fermat's little theorem, $a^3\equiv a\bmod 3$,

and by induction $a^{2k+1}\equiv a\bmod 3$, so $a^{48m+1}\equiv a\bmod 3$.

Likewise, $a^{13}\equiv a\bmod 13,$  so $a^{12n+1}\equiv a\bmod 13$, so $a^{48m+1}\equiv a\bmod 13$.

Therefore, $a^{48 m+1}\equiv a\bmod 39$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you explain more why $a^{13}\equiv a \pmod{13} $ then $a^{12n+1} \equiv a \pmod{13} $ and why $a^{12n+1} \equiv a \pmod{13} $ then $a^{48m+1} \equiv a \pmod{13}$? Thank you.

Comment: to answer the second part of your comment, take $n=4m$, so $48m+1=12(4m)+1$

Comment: Ok I see, thank you.

Comment: for the first part, do you know mathematical induction?  base case $n=1$:  $a^{13}\equiv a$, now if $a^{12(n-1)+1}\equiv a$ then $a^{12n+1}=a^{13}a^{12(n-1)}\equiv aa^{12n-12}\equiv a^{12n-11}\equiv a^{12(n-1)+1}\equiv a$